# For an R data.table, how do I determine the current ordering

Tags: r, data.table

I'm looking for something for setorder() that does what the key() function does for setkey().  That is, what do I put in the first line of fn3?  As it stands, the last line of output from fn1() is 1:10 instead of 10:1

```
fn1 <- function() {
  dt1 <- data.table(a = 1:10, b = 10:1)

  setkey(dt1, a)
  print(dt1[, b])
  fn2(dt1)
  print(dt1[, b])

  setorder(dt1, a)
  print(dt1[, b])
  fn3(dt1)
  print(dt1[, b])
}
fn2 <- function(dt2) {
  keys <- key(dt2)
  setkey(dt2, b)
  setkeyv(dt2, keys)
}
fn3 <- function(dt2) {
  #How do I extract the current ordering of dt2? e.g., ord <- getorder(dt2)
  setorder(dt2, b)
  #Restore the original ordering of dt2: setorderv(dt2, ord)
}
```

Comment: `dt2[, .o := .I]; setorder(dt2, b); setorder(dt2, .o)[, .o := NULL]` ?

Comment: Thanks, Frank - that is really ingenious and works for me - but only because I'm not modifying the data.table's contents in fn3() at present.  Is there a way to extract the column names/numbers used in the setorder() so that fn3() can restore the order that fn1() expects even when it changes the data in the columns that fn1() uses to order by?  I'd prefer not to wrapper setorder and use a setattr() call to store the order passed to setorder/v().  I don't want to use the key()/setkey() approach of fn2() because my understanding is that it physically reorders the rows and is hence inefficient.

Comment: Not sure I follow. If you want to store the arguments to `setorder` as an attribute of the object, you'll essentially be forking data.table to create a new class of object..? That's beyond my skill set. If it's a matter of nested function calls, I guess the "ordering variables" can be passed as an additional argument along side the data.table. Fwiw, both setorder and setkey physically reorder the data; only `setattr` adjusts without touching the core data.

Comment: Thanks again, Frank.  I somehow got the idea that setorder() used secondary indices.  Given that setorder() physically reorders, I might as well use setkey/key and save myself a lot of grief.  Fortunately for now I can just use your first proposal since fn3 doesn't modify the existing data.  Best regards, Jim.

Comment: The `indices` function could have confirmed there are no secondary indices assigned by `setorder`. You may want to use `setindex` if keeping track of this is important.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
if(is.unsorted(dt2[,a])){
  ord <- "b"
} else {
  ord <- "a"
}
```

Check out `?is.unsorted()`

Comment: Thanks, simone.  The problem with this approach is that in the real app there are many fn1()'s that call a single fn3 and fn3 doesn't know what order any particular caller is using so I cannot hard code fn3 to restore any particular order.

Comment: maybe `attributes(dt1)$sorted` can be of some use

Answer (score 0):

There's an unexported function in `data.table` called `is.sorted` that does what you want. Of course it's not recommended to rely on unexported functions as they can change unannounced. It requires you to have an idea what columns could have been used to sort the table in the first place.

```
data.table:::is.sorted(dt, 'a')
# [1] TRUE
# Warning message:
# In data.table:::is.sorted(dt1, "a") :
#   Use 'if (length(o<-forderv(DT,by))) ...' for efficiency in one step, so you have o as well if not sorted.
```

Note the warning as even internally it's not really used that much. Per the comments in the source code:

> This is only here for user/debugging use to check/test valid keys; e.g. `data.table:::is.sorted(DT,by)`